# Radar search for Google Places API returns too few results

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to extract the Google Places API data for all (or most of the) Chase Banks in NYC. I run a radar search, defining the location as a midpoint in Manhattan. I then specify various name, keyword and type parameters, all with variations on "chase" or "chase|bank" or "type=bank" (subsequently request Details for each returned result via the details API). In all cases, the API returns about 16 "Chase Bank" 's. I know from looking at Google Maps and from practical experience that there are a lot more than 16 Chase Banks (more like 140).

Here's an example query:

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=40.756121,-73.980694&radius=15000&type=bank&keyword=chase&key=XXXXXXX"
```

I've tried the same with and without "type" defined, just the name, name and keyword, etc. I've even tried just pulling "type=bank", which returns the full 200 results, but within those 200 returned results, still only about 16 Chase Banks.

What gives? Does this have something to do with the "prominence" rank?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. The problem was with the syntax of my API call. For keywords, names, etc., I was using a pipe operator instead of a "+" sign. The documentation is, IMO, a *bit* misleading:

> name — One or more terms to be matched against the names of places,
>   separated by a pipe symbol (term1|term2|etc).

I take it that "termX" means individual search terms, not individual words. For example, if you want to search for "Chase Bank", the correct syntax is `"keyword=chase+bank"`, NOT `"keyword=chase|bank"`. If instead I wanted to search for "TD Bank" and "Chase Bank", it would be `"keyword=chase+bank|td+bank"`